# How to get content of div which contains JavaScript script blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="example">
  ...some text...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ... some javascript...
  </script>
</div>
```

How to get content of `#example` but also with the JavaScript?

```
$("#example").html(),
$("#example").text(),     
$("#example").val()
```

all don't work.

Comment: your javascript does not belong there

Comment: $.html() should have worked. i wonder why.

Answer (score 11):

The `html()` method should work for you. Are you sure you are running the code after the DOM is completed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("#example").html());
});
```

Comment: .html() will strip out all <script> tags from returned html.

Comment: is there any solution to this question? I can also confirm THAT IT STRIPS OUT the javascript.

Answer (score 5):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/izuvo)

You can use

[html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html): Get the html contents (innerHTML) of the first matched element.

```
var contents = $("#example").html();
```

Comment: when i use $("#example").html();    i get only content of div, but without that javascript,  it ignores all javascript

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$("#example").get().innerHTML;
```

That gets the DOM object from the jQuery object and spits out the raw content.

Comment: think you meant:
$("#example").get(0).innerHTML;

Get with no params returns an array. This also suffers from the same issues though I think. We have a problem where all text inside tags is being cap'sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML;
```

This will fetch you the innertext of div. Write this line **at end of your body tag**. 
Or 
call it in a method which will be called after **body onLoad**

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it and $('#example').html() does work in isolation:

```
<html>
<head>    
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js' lang='text/javascript' />    
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
  ...some text...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ... some javascript...
  </script>
</div>

<script>
alert($('#example').html());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--This code will work -->
<html>
<head>    
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" lang='text/javascript' />-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//alert($('#example p').html());
alert($('#example').text());

alert($('#example #1').text());
alert($('#example #2').text());
alert($('#example #3').text());
alert($('#example #4').text());
//alert($("#example p").get().innerHTML);
//alert('hey');


}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
  <p>...some text...</p>
  <div id="1">
    Here's 1
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    Here's 2
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    Here's 3
  </div>
  <div id="4">
    Here's 4
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to add some description to your solution to explain what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuItem.firstChild.innerHTML
```

Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
$("#example").contents()

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am getting an html snippet back from a web service (as a property in an object returned as JSON).  I want to display it without formatting, and also without javascript blocks.  The `.html()` does return the javascript blocks for me, so that doesn't work.

What I ended up with was:

```
// Build up the message a bit artificially for this demo.
// is actually response from ajax call
var message = '<scri';
message += 'pt type="text/javascript">var foo = "bar";</scr'
message += 'ipt><h2>A heading</h2><div>This is a message</div>';

var message_html = jQuery('<div/>') // create a container
   .html(message) // set the contents from the message
   .find('script') // find script blocks
   .remove() // and remove them
   .end(); // back to the original collection but without script blocks
// Now get just the text from there
alert(message_html.text());
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qseudv4a/)